# Acceleration goes to zero when opposite direction is quickly pressed in succession to last one.

Tags: python, pygame, game-physics

This is my code in my Hero class (the one the player controls) that runs every update:

```
self.speedx += ((self.dirx * self.maxspeed) - self.speedx) * self.acc
self.x+=self.speedx
self.speedy += ((self.diry * self.maxspeed) - self.speedy) * self.acc
self.y+=self.speedy
```

This is my event getterizer code:

```
if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                active.dirx=0
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                active.dirx=0
            if event.key == K_UP:
                active.diry=0
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                active.diry=0
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                active.dirx=1
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                active.dirx=-1
            if event.key == K_UP:
                active.diry=-1
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                active.diry=1
```

The problem is that when I go right for awhile (or up) and then let go and quickly press the opposite direction (left, down) my acceleration for that direction goes to zero. This would not be much of a problem if the game did not involve a lot of reflex and I can't have players crapping out in the middle of a fight.

Any solutions? If I was not clear enough just say.

Comment: what's the desired effect?

Comment: Do you really mean that your acceleration goes to zero? or is it your speed?

Comment: If it is not responsive enough, maybe decrease the accel, add friction, or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that the opposite KEYDOWN event is being received before the KEYUP.  I would guard the KEUP event handling to make sure the opposite KEYDOWN has not occurred.  Something like:

```
if event.key == K_RIGHT and active.dirx == 1:
      active.dirx=0

...
```

Comment: Awesome this worked! Thanks so much. I feel so stupid for not getting it.